# How to make a kml file in Android?

Tags: android, kml, android-maps

Basically all I want to know is, is how does kml work and how would I implement it into my app. I am not a beginner but I am not advanced so if there is a place I can go to read about this stuff or if anyone has some info that they can post it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know how KML works go there: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html

Basically it's just XML fields to set. The process of writting object to xml file is `serialization`. I recomend searching google for it with android.

You can also get infos on this page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#list11